# Как узнать message_ids определённого сообщения в лс?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пишу бота в вк. Хочу, чтобы после отправки он удалял сообщение в личных сообщениях, но не знаю как получить идентификатор сообщения (message_ids).

Comment: Если бот использует пользовательское API, то приходит ответ после отправки сообщения, читайте абзац "Результат": `https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send`

Comment: @Volkodaff, спасибо!